# GoDaddy can't select database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running this code on GoDaddy webhosting and I'm getting 'The database could not be found' echoed.

Obviously the database in question can't be selected, even though I've privileged the user and checked the db name.

I don't get anything out of here `mysqli_error()`

```
$db= 'test2' ;

$con = mysqli_connect('whatever','whatever','whatever') or die ('The connection to the database could not be established.');
mysqli_select_db($db , $con) or die ('The database could not be found' . mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Replace `'The database could not be found'` with `mysqli_connect_error() `

Comment: @user3783243 Wouldn't that only show an error from `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, seeing your answer seems the issue was later. The `mysqli_select_db` should be part of the `connection` error message though I'd assume.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) documentation, it expects the parameters this way:

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname ) : bool
```

So your parameters are put in backwards, change it to this:

```
mysqli_select_db($con, $db) ...
```

Or, alternatively, just select the database inside [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

```
$con = mysqli_connect('whatever','whatever','whatever', $db) ...
```

---

Side note, your [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) isn't really doing anything, you won't get an actual error code out of that. To use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), you need to pass your database handle:

```
die('There was an error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```

For the [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) that is attached to `mysqli_connect()`, you should do this:

```
die('There was an error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, this helped me.